# ClassNotFoundException : com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJccSQLJConnection while using Liberty Profile v16.0.0.3

Tags: websphere, classnotfoundexception, websphere-liberty

I am migrating to the WebSphere Liberty Profile (version 16.0.0.3).

On server startup, I am getting the following exception.

```
[err] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJccSQLJConnection
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:488)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:797)
[err]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:775)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:466)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:752)
[err]   ... 87 more
```

Is it due to Classloading issue, or the Liberty Profile does not support it ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you trying to explicitly classload `WSJccSQLJConnection`?  Or is it an implicit classload from somewhere else.  This class does not exist in Liberty.

Comment: Maybe share your config (server.xml) and mention what code is loading this (or include the full stack trace).

Comment: I suggest showing the stack trace from `messages.log` rather than `console.log` so that the `at [internal classes]` will be expanded to show more details.

Comment: is jdbc feature included in your server.xml?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari yes, i have jdbc included in my server.xml `<featureManager>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
     <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
</featureManager>`

Comment: @aguibert this class is being implicitly loaded.

Comment: interesting.  Can you update your question with the complete stack trace?  As well as any code examples that lead up to the CNFE